# Back button to main section Ruby on Rails Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

About Us --> Board of directors --> single director (Articles)

Take Action --> General Causes --> Single Causes (Article)

Looking for work --> Types of job --> Description of job --> another content (Article)

When you are in the deeper level, I need a button that send to you to the main page, in each case is:

- Board of directors
- General Causes
- Description of job

The button must contain the name of the "main page" and the link of course. To be honest, I don't have to much idea about how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is essentially a breadcrumb. There is a great gem for doing this type of UI in Ruby on Rails. Check out the [Breadcrumbs on Rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) gem